# jquery mobile interspaced between image1 and image2

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile

I have a question on jquery.mobile. I can show the 2 photo on my mobile. But it has interspaced between photo1 and photo2.
Could you give any ideas , I don't want to a space between objects.
many thanks.

css

```
.ui-grid-b img {
   width  : 50%;
   height : 52vw;
```

}

html

```
<div class="ui-grid-b">

        <a href="xxx.htm">
        <img alt="alt..." src="img/image.jpg" />
        </a>
        <a href="xxx.htm">
        <img alt="alt..." src="img/image.jpg" />
        </a>
        <a href="xxx.htm">
        <img alt="alt..." src="img/image.jpg" />
        </a>
        <a href="xxx.htm">
        <img alt="alt..." src="img/image.jpg" />
        </a>
    </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
.ui-grid-b {
   line-height  : 0;
}
```